# change height of table row with C# Open XML and Word docx documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx

I have a table in a docx file and i want to proccess it and change the height of a row.Here is my code so far

```
WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("path_to_file", true) ;

Table table = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().ElementAt(1);

TableRow row = table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1);
```

What i want is to change the height of a table row (to zero so that i can hide it in certain circumstances). The problem proves to be harder than it seems...

Answer (score 1):

After you have the row object, try this piece of code

```
TableRowHeight trh = row.OfType<TableRowHeight>().FirstOrDefault();
trh.Val = 0;
```

I highly recommend you use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425), that way you'll have a better idea of what you're working with.

hope this helps.

Comment: The above selector doesn't work for me, correct one is :
    _row.TableRowProperties.OfType<TableRowHeight>().FirstOrDefault();